# How to reset heroku db on each build or periodically

Tags: php, heroku, laravel, composer-php, heroku-postgres

I have a demo app in heroku (using https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php , composer an Laravel 4) which database I want to be nuked everyday and then reinstall laravel migrations and seeds again (without messing with migration rollbacks).

For artisan commands there's no problem using Heroku Scheduler (free), but the `heroku pg:reset` command is not available under the server bash.

Any ideas, please?